# How to get a value from a three-level depth relation in Laravel using Eloquent?

Tags: laravel, eloquent-relationship

I have 3 tables as below:

**Users Table** (has only one phone):

| id | Name | phone_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Sam | 1 |
| 2 | Tom | 2 |

```php
/**
* @return HasOne
*/
public function phone()
{
    return $this->hasOne(phones::class);
}

/**
* @return ???
*/
public function key()
{
    return ???;
}
```

**Phone Table** (has only one key):

| id | Name | key_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Nokia | 1 |
| 2 | Samsung | 2 |

```php
/**
* @return HasOne
*/
public function key()
{
    return $this->hasOne(keys::class);
}
```

**Key Table**:

| id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | asd123 |
| 2 | qwe345 |

```php
/**
* @return belongTo
*/
public function phone()
{
    return $this->belongTo(phones::class);
}
```

I wanted to know how to get the key from the user model:

```php
User::find(1)->key()->Name
```

Comment: Do you have any **specific** question about this? Anything not working? Also, how would you define the "best relation"?

Comment: any specific question about this? Anything not working? Also, how would you define the "best relation" 1: How to get key from user model. 2: I do not know how to get key from user model. 3: corrected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to work around `hasOneThrough` to get what you need.

let's break it down, based on your schema:

- a `User` belongs to one `Phone`
- a `phone` belongs to `Key`
- therefore, a `User` belongs to `Key` through `Phone`

making this clear, we need to declare our `key` relationship inside the `User` model:

```
public function key()
{
    return $this->hasOneThrough(
        Key::class,       // model we are trying to get
        Phone::class,      // model we have an _id to
        'id',                 // WHERE `phone`.`id` = `user`.`phone_id`
        'id',                 // `key`.`id`
        'phone_id',        // local column relation to our through class
        'key_id'          // `phone`.`key_id`
    );
}
```

this will get you directly `key` from `user`

Comment: hasOneThrough() cannot be used in this case as I do not store phone_id on keys model.

Comment: @buczo i have updated my answer entirely, i think this should work.

Comment: Yes that's work as expected! Awesome!

Comment: notice that there's a package that you can add, to use `belongsToThrough` directly, without writing this method everytime. https://github.com/staudenmeir/belongs-to-through

Comment: note than you need to use `belongsTo` instead of `hasOne` in the first two mentioned relationships.

Answer (score 0):

Since a user can have only one phone (as mentioned) and phone has one key you have to use hasOneThrough() relation in model A.

Functions:

```
Public function getKey()
{
    Return $this->hasOneThrough(‘App\Models\Keys’, ‘App\Models\Phone’, ‘foreignKey on Phones’, ‘foreignKey on Keys’);
}
```

Note: For this to work you have to pick top to down approach so make migrations like this User->Phones->Keys.

There is another package that allow belongsToThrough i think its called haven’t used it tho if you want to look into reverse relation lookup (idk why someone need that :))